# Android Java accessing objects of a ROOM Database

Tags: java, android, database, list, android-room

I am trying to write an android app with a room database implemented. i followed a tutorial to setup the Database (honestly not fully understanding everything that i have done).

From the Database i am getting a "LiveData< List< Player>>"  Object with all "Player"s in my Table.
Each player has a Name and a Price.

I want to add up all prices and get a average value when adding a new player. But the code from me always disregards the last entry and only does the calculation for everything in the List except the last player. Where is my error?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

       // Add a New Player to the Database
            int preis = data.getExtras().getInt("EXTRA_REPLY_PREIS");
            String name = data.getExtras().getString("EXTRA_REPLY_NAME");
            Player player = new Player(name, preis);
            mPlayerViewModel.insert(player);

      // Populate the TextView "durchschnitt" with the average Value of all players, calculated in durchschnittspreis()
            TextView durchschnitt = findViewById(R.id.tvPreis);
            LiveData<List<Player>> alleSpieler = mPlayerViewModel.getAllPlayers();
            durchschnitt.setText("" + durschnittspreis(alleSpieler));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.empty_not_saved,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

```
 public int durschnittspreis(LiveData<List<Player>> players) {
        int durchschnittspreis = 0;
        int preis = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < players.getValue().size(); i++) {
            preis = preis + players.getValue().get(i).getPreis();
            System.out.println(preis);
            durchschnittspreis = preis / players.getValue().size();
        }
        return durchschnittspreis;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but did you try changing the loop condition in durschnittspreis function like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= players.getValue().size(); i++)
```

Comment: yes i tried that, that yield an ArrayOutOfBound Exception

Comment: umm then can you show me the query getting list of players from the database

Comment: my query looks like this:
```
    @Query("SELECT * from Spieler_gekauft ORDER BY id")
    LiveData<List<Player>> getAllById();
```
i honestly am not quite in understanding how everything works together, but i have:
- a ViewModel Class. This Class gets the players from a Repository Class. the Repository Class has an instance of the DAO class and in the DAO i have my queries

Comment: check the size of players.getValue().size() and the number of objects in the database, whether both are same?

Comment: moreover, make sure the last entry is committed in the database otherwise when accessing the that row will not be included

Comment: i found my error.i had to call the "durchschnittspreis()" function on a different spot (placed it in the ViewModel onChanged() function now

Comment: that's great. did my answer help you?